# Formatting a React table which receives data from a JSON file

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, html-table

I am currently working on a project to learn React, and I am attempting to display a table where the fields are values taken from a .json file. I am trying to format the table so that there is a line separating each row and each column, but all I've been able to get is a box around each individual table entry. Here is the code for my class:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import table from '../styles/table.css'
import PostData from '../data/week1scoring.json'

class PostList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table style={{"borderWidth":"1px", u'borderStyle':'solid'}}>
          <tr>
                <th>Team</th>
                <th>Points Scored</th>
                <th>Quarterback</th>
          </tr>
        </table>
          {PostData.map((postDetail, index)=>{
          return (
            <table style={{"borderWidth":"1px", 'borderStyle':'solid'}}>
                <tr>
                    <td>{postDetail.team}</td>
                    <td>{postDetail.points}</td>
                    <td>{postDetail.qb}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PostList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it makes more sense to do the following. Also  I would say that your real problem is not about React but the styling and css. Inspect your table in the web browser and have a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp) example.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import table from '../styles/table.css'
    import PostData from '../data/week1scoring.json'

    class PostList extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <table style={{"borderBottom":"1px solid black","borderCollapse":"collapse";}}>
              <tr>
                    <th style={{"border": "1px solid black"}}>Team</th>
                    <th style={{"border": "1px solid black"}}>Points Scored</th>
                    <th style={{"border": "1px solid black"}}>Quarterback</th>
              </tr>
              {PostData.map((postDetail, index)=>{
              return (
                    <tr>
                        <td style={{"border": "1px solid black"}}>{postDetail.team}</td>
                        <td style={{"border": "1px solid black"}}>{postDetail.points}</td>
                        <td style={{"border": "1px solid black"}}>{postDetail.qb}</td>
                    </tr>
              )
            })}
            </table>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

export default PostList;
```

An even better way would be to add

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

into the table.css file you import.

Comment: I'm planning on expanding the .css file I just wanted to make sure the formatting was right first